# How and when to use .on or Events : {} with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, qunit, sinon

I am building a web app using backbone and im keep running in a problem where my events do not properly bind to the according objects.

I am using backbone in combination with qunit and sinon for testing.
I want to catch connection errors if they are being made.
My understanding of the backbone collection is that whenever `collection.create()` is called backbone will save the new model to the server through the collection so the `"request"`, `"sync"` or possibly `"error"` events should be called. So in my collection i have added:

```
var CProduct = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // Code

    events : {
        'sync' : 'success',
        'error' : 'fail'
    },
    success : function()
    {
        console.log('success');
    },
        fail: function()
    {
        console.log('sync error');
    },

    // More code
});
```

At some other point in my code this is triggered by a button click:

```
createProduct
{
    alert('creating model');
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var description = $('#description').val();
    this.collection.create({'title':title,'description':description});
}
```

Where the alert is to check if this particular event by click is fired
and collection is the CProduct collection. Note that this is in a view containing the collection.

I use sinon to fake a server call and repley with the following code:

```
module("Product models",{
    setup: function(){
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    },
    teardown: function(){}
}

asyncTest("someTest", 1 , function(){

    //Some preparation code

    var test = function(eventData) {
         console.log(eventData);
         server.respond();
    };

    server.respondWith("GET", "/api/testmodel/1",[500, 
         { "Content-Type": "application/json"}, JSON.stringify({"FAIL":"ERROR"})]);
     //trying to make it fail
    cproduct.on('request', test);
    new ExpandProductFrom({'collection':cproduct});
}
```

But after this all neither of the events is triggered. So after having taken a look at the backbone api i found `.on` binding events to objects. So i replaced `events : {}` with :

```
initialize : function()
{
    this.on('sync',this.success);
    this.on('error',this.fail);
}
```

This made the success function run only if i corrected the `respondWith` function.

To comeback to my question: 
How do i properly use `events:{}` or the `.on` function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is...

events:{}

> This property is to capture the delegate events that happening in DOM(templates).
>
> e.g., button click event

on()/bind()

> These methods is to capture internal events happening inside backbone
>
> eg., collection/model add event

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Out-of-the-box, you need to use `.on` and preferably `listenTo` if you're in a view.

There are some plugins which will provide the functionality you're looking for, but its not in the core.

Comment: Well the problem is the the error event is not being fired when i make it fail

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two kind of events, let me explain:

- The `events` attribute in `Backbone.View` is used to listen to events triggered by the DOM elements and more precisely DOM element within the View `$el`
- The `.on` method is used to listen to events triggered by any jQuery object (including `Backbone.Collection`)
- The `.listenTo` method is more preferably than jQuery `.on` because it extends it and add more functionalities to the events model, take a look at the [Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo)

Comment: Note that the `.on()` method used by the original poster is a method on Backbone.Events, and it has nothing to do with jQuery (which has it's own event API that includes a method called `.on()`).